# Spring data JPA (EclipseLink) and calculated column

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have query:

```
select id, column1, column2, get_status_text_by_id(id) as status from table1
```

How i can cast column `'status'` `(some_procedure(id))` in EclipseLink jpa?

p.s. I'm used Oracle database

Comment: You mean JPQL "TREAT" ? An internet search would give all details you need. And JPQL does not use "table"s

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. I can use `get_status_text_by_id(id)` as column name

```
@Column(name="(get_status_text_by_id(id)",insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String status;
```